# Research topics “belonging” to a school

Tags: mathematics, ethics, research-topic

I heard that in some scientific schools it is typical that certain research topics “belong” to the school, and people from other schools are not welcome to work on them.
**I am wondering how popular is this point of view today? Is it something standard?** I am particularly interested in mathematics.

Comment: Can you give me one example in the history of math where certain "schools" were not welcome to work on a specific *topic*? There have been unfortunate episodes of valuing one methodological approach over another (the priority dispute and Nazi Germany come to mind), but I'd be curious to see what you are referring to.

Comment: I just heard it on the level of rumors from colleagues. I do not want to repeat them here as I did not check them. I do not know history of science to give such examples. Instead of downvoting the question, a more concrete answer would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4):

No, its not true in any real sense. Ideas are free, though we honor creators by avoiding plagiarism.

But English is a funny language, both having many roots and being vibrant with a large speaking base. So, a colloquial meaning of "own" might mean that someone or a group is so good at something and does so much of it that they seem to have made it "their own".

In that sense, it might have been said, at one time, that MIT "owned" AI research, or Stanford "owned" functional programming research.

But the sense of "not being welcome" is pure hubris, which exists, certainly, but isn't valid and no reason for others to avoid research areas.

Funny that  you mention mathematics. It might once have been said that I "owned" classical real analysis, but only because I was the "last guy standing" when everyone else went in other directions. My research was "very cool" (IMO) but only a very few people were interested by then. (Caveat: no one said that, to my knowledge.)